# How to calculate the widths of grandchildren div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Good afternoon fellows,

I'm having trouble with some jQuery-code and I can't seem to grasp the problem.

The situation is as follows:

I'm making (based on mysql-entries) a couple of div's. Perhaps it's better if I show you the result first:

```
<div class="shipcontainer" id="shipcontainer1">
    <div class="timelinecontainer" id="timelinecontainer1">timeline--></div>
    <div class="travelsall" data-ship="1">
        <div class="travelcontainer" data-travelid="1" data-ship="1" id="travelcontainer1">
         <div class="fasecontainer" data-travelid="1" data-ship="1">
           <div class="Mobilize  travelfase" date-days="6" date-fasetravelid="1">1: Mobilize </div>
           <div class="Loading travelfase" date-days="12" date-fasetravelid="1">2: Loading</div>
           <div class="Boating travelfase" date-days="20" date-fasetravelid="1">3: Boating</div>
           <div class="Discharge travelfase" date-days="6" date-fasetravelid="1">4: Discharge</div>
        </div>
        <div class="options" id="optionstravel1" data-travelid="1">OPTIONS</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a shipcontainerdiv. Within i have two child-divs (timelinecontainer and travelsall). The latter contains in this example only one ".travelcontainer", but there will be more in the future.

This piece of code is repeated a couple of times, (I currently have two ".shipcontainers").

What I wanted to achieve was to set the width of the div with ".travelcontainer" to the sum of the widths of the four div's with ".travelfase". This is my jQuery code:

```
var totalWidth = 0;

$(".travelcontainer").width(function () {
  var travelID = $(this).data(travelid);

  $(this).find('div[data-fasetravelid=' + travelID + ']').each(function (index, element) {
    totalWidth = $(this).innerWidth() + totalWidth;
  });

  return totalWidth;
});
```

Because, during it's parsing through PHP, I gave the ".travelcontainer" a data-travelid attribute, and also it's ".travelfase" grandchildren. I figured I could couple them together this way.

The problem is that when I have 2 shipcontainers, with both a "travelcontainer" it's adding all values together. So travelcontainer with data-travelid=1, has the width of exactly the same as all div's with class travelfase, instead of only the div's with the data-fasetravelid=1 attribute.

I've also tried this code (which I've used earlier):

```
var widthTotal = 0;

$(".travelcontainer").width(function () {
  $(".travelcontainer > .travelfase").each(function (index, element) {
    widthTotal = $(this).innerWidth() + widthTotal;
  });
});

return widthTotal;
```

This also has the same effect.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you notice the `data-` vs. `date-` confusion?

Comment: Well the travelfalse DIVs are children of the travelcontainer DIV, so ordinarily the latter would be stretched by the children anyway. Or is there absolute positioning going on?

Comment: @jensgram: Very sharp, thank you! Still though, no joy, effect is the same. I think there is something wrong with the selector, because
    var travelIDa = $("#travelcontainer1").data(travelid);
    alert("hoi" + travelIDa); 

doesn't do anything. Strange.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't do this with plain css?

Comment: @Utkanos : I've read that $(".class < .otherclass") only selects the direct children of .class, not grandchildren.

Comment: I was talking general box-model/CSS, no JS required. A container is naturally stretched to snap to the resultant dimensions of its contents - child or ancestor. This is disrupted only where absolute positioning is concerned.

Comment: No, the div's are going to be resizable, and the container is draggable. The width of the container needs to be the exact size of the 4 childrendiv's together :) But thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".travelcontainer").each(function() {
  var totalWidth = 0;

  $('.travelfase', this).each(function () {
    totalWidth += $(this).width();
  });

  $(this).width(totalWidth);
});
```

Comment: This did the trick! I've made it to complicated, thank you very much :)